# Error to connect Pusher channel in Laravel on Heroku app

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, deployment, pusher

I have a problem connecting the Pusher channel on Heroku to my Laravel app. It works locally, but in production it gives an error. I have already added the Pusher variables to i reavel variables in heroku and also in laravel's .env.

The error in **console.log**:

> Uncaught You must pass your app key when you instantiate Pusher.

REVEAL COFING VARS

```
app_id = "1682617"
key = "4******************e"
secret = "3******************a"
cluster = "mt1"
```

CREDENTIALS DEVELOPMENT

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1682617
PUSHER_APP_KEY=c******************3
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=f******************1
PUSHER_HOST=ws-mt1.pusher.com
```

Bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

 window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'pusher',
   key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
   wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
   wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
   wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
   forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
   enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* have an **.env** being pushed to Heroku, as that’s the entire point of config vars in your Heroku app. It also suggests you’re keeping your **.env** file with sensitive values in your Git repository that again, you do *not* want to be doing.

If you look in your **bootstrap.js** file, you’ll also notice it’s referencing environment variables with a `VITE_*` prefix, i.e. `VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY`. So whilst you are (correctly) setting config vars for Pusher (`PUSHER_APP_ID`, etc) you still need to set the equivalents with the `VITE_*` prefix.

You should also add the `nodejs` build pack to your app if you haven’t already. You need to add this in addition to the `php` build pack. Heroku will then run your `npm run build` when deploying, which will build your JavaScript files using the values of the config vars in your Heroku app, and not the values from where ever you were running it before (I’m guessing either your computer, or not at all).

To summarise:

1. Remove any **.env** files from your repository: `git rm -f .env`
2. Add the `nodejs` build pack to your Heroku app
3. Remove assets if you‘ve started tracking them: `git rm -rf public/hot && git rm -rf public/storage`
4. Re-add lines to your **.gitignore** file to ignore the above files
5. Add config vars to your Heroku app for:

   - `VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY`
   - `VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER`
   - `VITE_PUSHER_HOST`
   - `VITE_PUSHER_PORT`
   - `VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME`
6. Commit and push. Heroku should now run `npm run build` when deploying.

Comment: I think it worked. Thank you very much!